# Extra characters within parentheses in a line

Tags: excel

I have the following:

```
Funny Card (dwi) Fun Card (han) Cool Card (job)
```

I want to it to become:

```
dwi han job
```

I've done this through Excel using the `RIGHT` function, but only for single parentheses:

```excel
=RIGHT(A2,LEN(A2)-FIND(" (",A2))
```

I want the output of `Funny Card (dwi) Fun Card (han) Cool Card (job)` to become `dwi han job`.

Comment: Why is this tagged [tag:javascript]?

Comment: If you have Excel 2016 or Office 365 you can use the [TEXTJOIN function](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/textjoin-function-357b449a-ec91-49d0-80c3-0e8fc845691c) in an array formula to do this.  Otherwise you'll need the output to be in separate cells (or use VBA).

Comment: the vba alternative would be to loop through characters in the value and concatenate a string using what isn't started by "(" or closed by ")".  in that scnario, byte array is your friend

Comment: Will it always have 3 parentheses, or could it have a variable number?